# How to dynamically change table name in DynamoDbEnhancedClient (Aws Sdk V2 for Java)

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-java-2.0

In Aws SDK V1 for java when creating DynamoDBMapperConfig you could set

```
withTableNameResolver(...)
```

and

```
withObjectTableNameResolver(...)
```

to dynamically change table name before save operation occurred even if a bean had @DynamoDBTable annotation.

Is it possible to do something like this with DynamoDbEnhancedClient in Aws Sdk v2 for java?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, it can't be done as of now. You seem to be looking for this feature:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2935

Looks like it's in development (or at least accepted as a feature request)